# Is it correct to say "He is good with flying to Europe"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm trying to say that someone agrees to fly to Europe, is it correct to put it that way?

Comment: I think the _latest_ expression is "down" meaning good, okay, etc. as in, "He is down with _some activity_ …"

Comment: Could one say that "I'm down with (something)" suggests some measure of approval or interest, where "I'm good with (something)" is neutral, meaning only "that's OK, that's fine"? I think "I'm down with that" is, entertainly, similar to "I'm up for that".

Comment: *entertainingly

Comment: It's grammatically incorrect but consistent with accepted and very common US slang, so you will be understood in the US at least, and you'll probably be understood elsewhere also.

Answer (score 3):

"To be good with (something)" is very colloquial for "to find (something) acceptable or satisfactory", "to be satisfied with (something)". I think it's a fairly recent idiom, and I don't know how broadly used it is; I'm in the U.S. It's used correctly in your sentence, as long as such casual language is appropriate for the context.

So, "He is good with flying to Europe" means essentially that flying to Europe is fine with him.

Also: "Would you like another drink, sir?" "No, thanks, I'm good," meaning one is satisfied, has had one's fill.

Comment: +1, though if I heard this from a not-very-fluent speaker, I'd very likely ask follow-up questions to nake sure of the intended meaning. Some colloquialisms only really work for fluent speakers. So the OP might be better off using *OK with* instead of *good with*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, "He is agreeable to" flying to Europe.  This conveys the right shade of meaning.  It does not rule out reluctance on his part.

Answer (score -1):

Compare:

"He's flying to Europe"
"He's good flying to Europe."
"He's with flying to Europe."
"He's good with Europe."

In the end, it's kind of like responding to the quesion "Do you want more salad?" with "I'm good!"

You aren't really good, and even if you were, you could possibly eat more salad and not become bad. It is taken to mean, however, that you are in a state of contentment without more salad. It's bad English, but people understand it.

I would say "He is happy to fly to Europe."